# How to prevent firing single tap event when double tapped in NSTableView in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSTableVIew and when I try to double tapped on any row, two methods are getting called back to back first one is single tap action and the second one is double tapped action.
How to avoid calling single tap action when I double tap on row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using c# for Windows App and I faced a similar problem as you are. The way I used is based on a `Timer` named `DispatcherTimer`. Uh.. for c#.
First, I set a `Tick` event handler in which it would stop the timer and time interval for that `Timer`. Therefore, once I start the `Timer`, I can defer the action that I want to do for single-tap or double-tap. 
i.e.

Original:

```
1st tap-->action 1
          2nd tap --> action 2
```

By timer:

```
1st tap --( timer )--------->run action 1 or action 2 based on count.
          2nd tap --( count++)
```

Uh... Hope this concept is useful for you since we use different platform.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

`(void)setDoubleAction:(SEL)aSelector`

Comment: As I mentioned my doubleClick action is getting called, I just want to avoid calling single click (which is getting called before doubleCLick action) on doubleClick action.